# Wrong or Right? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 buttons, Correct & Wrong. When a random question (vragen) pops up on the screen, its index number [1] needs to be the same as the answer (antw) index number [1]. If pressed on the G button and its good it has to say yay, bad noo and when clicked on the F the same but then the other way!

```
window.onload = function start(){

var questions = [  "1 x 1 = 2",
    "1 x 1 = 1",
    "2 x 2 = 4",
    "7 x 7 = 49",
    "1 x 8 = 9",
    "8 x 1 = 8",
    "5 x 5 = 25",
    "3 x 5 = 2"
];
var answers = [    false,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                false,
                true,
                true,
                false
];

var rand = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];
var randans = answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * answers.length)];
document.getElementById('quizzy').innerHTML = rand + "<br>";

document.getElementById('G').onclick = check1;
document.getElementById('F').onclick = check2;
function check1(){
    if(rand == randans){
        alert("a!");
    }
}
};
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="section">
<h2>Goed of Fout?</h2>
<div id="quizzy"><script src="quiz.js"></script></div>
<img src="images/G_03.gif" width="200px" class="GF" id="G"/>
<img src="images/F_03.gif" width="200px" class="GF" id="F"/>
<img src="images/chick_03.png" width="100px" id="chick" />
```

Comment: share the HTML/fiddle mate

Comment: You don't need to check if *rand==randans*, because randans has nothing to do with rand

Comment: @DennisVanZanten, please don't use dutch variable names.

Comment: it should have same index but you d better to change structure to [{ 'question': "1 x 1 = 2", 'answer': false}, { 'question': "1 x 1 = 1", 'answer': true}] . So you won't need 2 indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Edit: this one works with jQuery.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var vragen = ["1 x 1 = 2",
        "1 x 1 = 1",
        "2 x 2 = 4",
        "7 x 7 = 49",
        "1 x 8 = 9",
        "8 x 1 = 8",
        "5 x 5 = 25",
        "3 x 5 = 2"
    ];
    var antw = [false,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        false
    ];

    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * vragen.length),
        rand = vragen[a];
    $('#quizzy').innerHTML = rand + "<br>";

    $(".GF").onclick(function(){
        if (antw[a] === true) {
            alert("a!");
        } else {
            alert("boo!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've explained yourself, what you want to do is to check that the "truthiness" of the answer (G=true and F=false) is equal to the value of `antw[randans]`.

So in `check1` it's `if( antw[randans] === true ){`

And you don't need `rand` at all, because you want to link the answer to the corresponding question, not a random one...